# Angular $cookieStore do not set key

Tags: angularjs

In app

```
 var appRoot = angular.module('AppRoot', ['AppRoot.Factory', 'AppRoot.Constants', 'ngResource', 'ui.router']);
 var factory = angular.module('AppRoot.Factory', ['ngCookies', 'ngDialog']);
 var constants = angular.module('AppRoot.Constants', []);
```

Cookie factory

```
///Cookie store service
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('AppRoot.Factory').factory('CookieFactory', ['$cookieStore',
    function ($cookieStore) {
        return {
            ///set value on key
            set: function (key, value) {
                if ('undefined' === typeof value)
                    value = '';

                $cookieStore.put(key, value);
            },
            ///return null or value of key
            get: function (key) {
                var value = $cookieStore.get(key);
                if ('undefined' === typeof value)
                    return null;

                    return value;
            },
            ///test if key exist in cookie store
            keyExist: function (key) {
                return 'undefined' === typeof ($cookieStore.get(key));
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

and I try to use like this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('AppRoot')
        .controller('RootController', ['$rootScope','CookieFactory',
            function ($rootScope,CookieFactory) {  
                CookieFactory.set('test', 'test');    
                var test = CookieFactory.get('test');     
            }]);
})();
```

but  **"var test" is  null** and if I try to call **CookieFactory.keyExist('test') return false**

I use  AngularJS v1.4.3 .

1. [Cookies set by this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsjZS.png)
2. [Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70T0n.png)

   What I do wrong?

edit:

```
///Cookie store service
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('AppRoot.Factory').factory('CookieFactory', ['$cookies',
        function ($cookies) {
            return {
                ///set value on key
                set: function (key, value) {
                    if ('undefined' === typeof value)
                        value = '';

                    $cookies.put(key, value);
                },
                ///return null or value of key
                get: function (key) {
                    var value = $cookies.get(key);
                    if ('undefined' === typeof value)
                        return null;

                        return value;
                },
                ///test if key exist in cookie store
                keyExist: function (key) {
                    return 'undefined' === typeof ($cookies.get(key));
                }
            }
        }]);
    })();
```

Comment: generally, cookieService has been depreciated. You should use $cookies.

Comment: same behavior with "$cookies"

Answer (score 1):

You use AngularJS v 1.4.3. $cookiesService has been depreciated in version 1.3. Use $cookies.

Here is example of how you can use it:

```
    angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

Comment: same behavior with "$cookies"